# What did kMaxLogLen become in cocos2dx3.2?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

When I'm writing "char szBuf【kMaxLogLen】;" xcode said:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'kMaxLogLen'

How to fix it? I'm using cocos2dx3.2 and xcode.

Comment: kMaxLogLen is not declared in the scope

Comment: thanks.God bless you~ By the way,I'm from China,well you know...

Answer (score 1):

It has been refactored to `MAX_LOG_LENGTH` and you can found in file
`cocos\base\CCConsole.h`